# Found nil unwrapping optional table view swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've got an error:

```
"Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
for cartTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CartTableViewCell")
```

This is my code. I'm using a storyboard for this view controller and a .xib file for the cell.

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CartTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        
        // error is below
        cartTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CartTableViewCell") 
        cartTableView.delegate = self
        cartTableView.dataSource = self 
    }
}

extension CartViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
```

I'm coming from a programmatic table view. This is how

```
  @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let cartVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartVC") as! CartViewController
        self.present(cartVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image: Cell]

Comment: `cartTableView` is nil. Did you connect it correctly in Storyboard?

Comment: @Larme Yes, is connected..

Comment: UINib(nibName: "CartTableViewCell", bundle: nil) - is nil if there's no nib file in the bundle with that name

Comment: Is `cartTableView` nil? If you do before that line `print(cartTableView)` is it crashing?

Comment: Hmm, is printing nil, but crashes at same line. Don't know why is nil, I have connected it. I have updated the post with TableViewCell.xib

Comment: @BeucaAlexandru try to disconnect `cartTableView` and connect it again

Comment: @KishanBhatiya tried it several times, dont know what s wrong ..

Comment: Because the outlet var is weak and the tableView's not held onto by the view hierarchy?

Comment: @Shadowrun I've deleted the weak but is the same

Comment: Got a screenshot how it is connected?

Comment: @Cora https://imgur.com/2QwCFHR

Comment: It's unclear. If it's `cartTableView` that is nil, it's the one causing the crash. The cell shouldn't matter here. Comment the rest, you'll see if it's still crash there.

Comment: @Larme is not crashing, it displaying a black screen , I tried it right now

Comment: THen is `CartTableViewCell` inside your target?$

Comment: @Larme I have tried to create another cell and assign it again, but I have same error. Maybe is this because im coming from a programmatically controller , where I don't use storyboards ?

Comment: Does your view controller have an identifier “CartVC”?

Comment: I have tried now with prototype cells and now I've got an error at a "cartTableView.delegate = self "

Comment: I think that the problems is how im going to CartViewController, because the previous controller is a programmatically one

Answer (score 0):

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "cart"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightButtonPressed(sender:)))
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [rightButton]



@objc func rightButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let cartVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartVC") as! CartViewController
    self.present(cartVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is working right now. My code was running from another function and that why was not working. This is the right code.